# Obtain type from nested method call using JDT and AST

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How can I infer the type of a nested method call such as:

```
JavaSourceFile javaSourceFile = new JavaSourceFile();

javaSourceFile.getClasses().size()
```

It works for normal method calls such as

```
javaSourceFile.getClasses()
```

But i would like to obtain the return type of getClasses(). This is what I do. In

```
ASTVisitor.visit(MethodInvocation invocation)
```

I want to obtain the type of the size() call. I use

```
    Expression expression = invocation.getExpression();
    if (expression != null) {

        ITypeBinding typeBinding = expression.resolveTypeBinding();
        if (typeBinding != null) {
            Call call = new Call(invocation.getName().getFullyQualifiedName(), typeBinding.getName());
            this.activeMethod.getCalls().add(call);
        }
    }
```

to obtain the type of a method invocation. But if there there is a method call as in  outlined at the start I just get null. I also use

```
invocation.resolveMethodBinding();
```

afterwards if the binding couldn't be resolved using the expression.

Comment: Where do you get null? Does invocation.getExpression() return null? Or are you talking aboput expression.resolveTypeBinding()? or typeBinding.getName()?

Comment: I get null from expression.resolveTypeBinding()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you have 2 method invocations. So your visitor will be called 2 times unless you return `false`.

First time you visit with this expression `javaSourceFile.getClasses().size()` and if you call `resolveTypeBinding()` you will actually get the type of `size()` method because it happens first.

However in your given code if your visitor was called with `javaSourceFile.getClasses().size()` then you are actually resolving type for `javaSourceFile.getClasses()`, because you used `getExpression()` method. (NOTE: if your visit method didn't return `false` it will be visited again as `javaSourceFile.getClasses()` (since it's method invocation as well) and then you will get type of `javaSourceFile` variable)

Also you said that you get `null` which I believe shouldn't happen if everything is set up properly (for example maybe you didn't specify classpaths/sourcepaths of some classes). Can't tell why that happens since I need full code.